# generating relatively prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $S: \mathbb{Z}_n\times \hspace{.1cm}\mathbb{Z}_n → \mathbb{Z}$ for n some natural number such that $S(a,b) = S_a(b) = f_1(a)*b + f_2(a)$ so it's a linear function in the 2nd parameter and the coefficients are functions of the 1st parameter. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are $\mathbb{Z}_n → \mathbb{Z}$.

I want that $f_1(a)$ always be relatively prime to n for all a, but not constant. Then the range of $S_a$ will be well defined mod n.

Just to provide context: I want to map letters in the alphabet a...z to other letters a...z using an [affine cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher). So for n=26 and any fixed a, S(a,b) should map letter "b" (that's a variable standing for any letter, not specifically b) to some other letter in a more or less "random" way. I know this isn't the cryptography exchange, but mathematically speaking it should be close to uniform on all numbers which, taken mod 26, are relatively prime to 26. Then other letters can be accessed by the shift part, $f_2(a)$.

Can anyone suggest functions particular good for this?

Comment: I suppose $\Bbb Z_n=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is the set of all integers modulo $n$. For $f_1(a)$ consider the function $a\mapsto m^a\mod n$, where $m\in(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = nx + 1$ maps an integer $x$ to another integer relatively prime to $n$ (and coincidentally, also to $x$). Generalizing, if $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then $f(x) = nx + a$ also satisfies the condition. There are $\phi(n)$ such positive numbers $a$ less than $n$, where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient function.

On a similar vein, if $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then $f(x) = a^x$ also works, but only for nonnegative $x$; similarly, we have $f(x) = n^x + a$.

I don't know about *all* such functions, but these are a few. You could choose a suitable form depending on what exactly you require.